# React JS - Link with data-toggle doesn't redirect to url

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a link from react router dom like this:

```
<Link
    to="/"
    data-target="#navbarDropdown"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    className="nav-link"
>
```

I want it to redirect to "/" and also toggle the collapsible menu in the navbar. But this code doesn't redirect to "/", it only toggles the menu. How do I redirect and toggle at the same time?

Comment: Does the redirection works when you remove `data-toggle`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<li data-toggle="collapse">
    <Link to="/" 
        data-target="#navbarDropdown"  
        className="nav-link">
    </Link>
</li>
```

Comment: data-target should also be in the <li> like this:

<li
    className="nav-item"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarDropdown"
>
    <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
        HOME
    </Link>
</li>